# Draw 2D images with, for example, a printer head, optimally

Tags: python, printing, drawing, traveling-salesman

I do not know whether I am on the right stackexchange for this type of question.

I have a machine which is similar to a printer. It deposits material on a surface like a pencil would draw on paper. I can feed this tip a list of coordinates to draw.

**My question is** : do you know algorithms that deal with 'filling a surface' with lines, such that the printer head would follow these lines in order to draw the surface ?

What I am looking for is something like this
[image]

This is python implementation I've done pretty quickly. The motif is white. The red lines is what I would like to find out efficiently. Here, I've created the adjacency matrix of the white pixels, and solved the traveling salesman problem on the pixels.

Anyway, I am not completely satisfied with this since it can be extremely slow. I wouldn't be satisfied either with simply horizontal or vertical slices of my image, because this would mean a lot of lifting/putting down the printer head. I would like it to stay in contact as long as possible with the substrate.

Regards

Comment: Finding it optimally probably can't get *that* much faster than you're doing, but heuristics could do well, how "optimally" do you need it?

Comment: Is there no algorithm that would treat larger images ? Calculating the distance matrix between pixels and solving the TSP on them can be quite time consuming (~several hours) when the pixel number exceeds 10k.

Is there no self-avoiding random walk solution that could be implemented ? I do not need to be optimal in the sense of shortest path, I just need to fill it in with enough lines to reproduce the pattern

Comment: Yeah, heuristics are definitely possible, it's just the "optimal" qualifier that made it really hard.

Comment: Do you have sources about such heuristic implementations, that do not have to be optimal, but simply have to work ? Then I can implement them and see for myself if I'm satisfied with the output.

Comment: I don't actually know. I'd guess you could use some broad phase planning with some hierarchical structure, like a voronoi diagram, triangulation, or quadtree or something, and then make a second path to generate a pretty good path. I think the terms you should search for are "tool path" planning algorithms, or just look at information about CAM software and perhaps look at how some open source CAM software handles it if you want to get really detailed.

Comment: There is a similar idea known as "TSP art" -- first generate points with varying densities to mimic a given image, then find a TSP through those points. Would that help? http://www.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/bosch/tspart-page.html

Comment: Hi Grendelsdad, 
Yes thanks. I figured this was what porglezomp's last comment was about. Maybe, in my case, I just need to find a way to distribute a set of points with a fixed density and then find the tsp through these points, where the density is proportional to the required resolution (the thicker the printer dot, the less resolution I'll have, so the less points I'll need to tsp through)